# How to put japan flag character  in a string?

Tags: javascript, unicode, emoji

We're trying to make a list of country flags, using unicode escapes (to avoid having unicode in the source code). We're using characters to represent the flags to allow the user to copy/paste the flags in plaintext content, and avoid the bandwidth of transmitting image files and dead links.

If I recall, in Java, you have to use a special sequence of unicode escapes when dealing with special characters. So I think it's the same in JS. I looked up the code for the Japan flag , and found this sequence: 1f1ef 1f1f5 (as seen in [this document](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/EmojiSources.txt) which translates from some other character sets to unicode sequences). So I thought the way to write the string would be `"\u1f1ef\u1f1f5"`, but that returns `"἞f἟5"`. What am I missing?

Comment: your browser's font might not have those unicode characters. This could be an issue for potential users as well...

Comment: I think you'd use &#x1f1ef&#x1f1f5

Comment: yep, I don't see it my browser, if you want to avoid images use [data in src](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML)

Comment: @vladkras: Then I have to transfer 3x the amount of data as I would if I used plain images, as well as lose copy/paste ability. We tested the flags on our target browsers they work.

Comment: Here's a [picture](https://image.bayimg.com/7a34cd76c2672e44cd7d7a519ddebf67f20c5f01.jpg) for anyone who can't see the character.

Comment: @Dog no, they are not, I still see two squares, maybe you have extended character set or additional fonts installed on the machine for testing

Answer (score 6):

I know it's an old question. Though, the following implementation might be useful for future readers. Solution runs in ECMAScript 2015.

```js
// Create flag from country code
function getCountryFlag(cc) {
  // Mild sanity check.
  if (cc.length !== 2)
    return cc;

  // Convert char to Regional Indicator Symbol Letter
  function risl(chr) {
    return String.fromCodePoint(0x1F1E6 - 65 + chr.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0));
  }

  // Create RISL sequence from country code.
  return risl(cc[0]) + risl(cc[1]);
}

// Test
document.write(getCountryFlag('jp'));
```

Answer (score 0):

comments are too small too post this:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" />
```

and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UmnGq/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because character in question must be represented as a Unicode surrogate. You can use following function to get proper encoded values:

```
function toUTF16(codePoint) {
    var TEN_BITS = parseInt('1111111111', 2);
    function u(codeUnit) {
        return '\\u'+codeUnit.toString(16).toUpperCase();
    }

    if (codePoint <= 0xFFFF) {
        return u(codePoint);
    }
    codePoint -= 0x10000;

    // Shift right to get to most significant 10 bits
    var leadSurrogate = 0xD800 + (codePoint >> 10);

    // Mask to get least significant 10 bits
    var tailSurrogate = 0xDC00 + (codePoint & TEN_BITS);

    return u(leadSurrogate) + u(tailSurrogate);
}
```

Sample:

```
> toUTF16(0x1f1ef)
"\uD83C\uDDEF" // this is ''
```

See further reference on [Unicode in JS](http://www.2ality.com/2013/09/javascript-unicode.html).

Comment: @Dog why do you think so?

Comment: Look at your sample, it's a different character (not the Japan flag).

Comment: @Dog the sequence you decribed (`1f1ef 1f1f5`) is 2 separate unicode characters  ('REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER J') and  ('REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER P'). What is all about the flag?

Comment: The sequence I got is supposed to be the special form that shows up as the flag once you make javascript render it. You seem to be splitting half of that sequence into another sequence? What's this about two separate characters?

Comment: @Dog the picture you attached as a comment is a Emoji to which this characters are converted on the fly by *your* browser. There is no `flag of Japan` character in Unicode.

Comment: eh? what you just described sounds like what a font does. I looked up what an [emoji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) is and it says in the second paragraph that they are part of unicode.

Comment: @Dog I guess you are probably right with font-level Emoji support. But anyway, my solution is a correct way to write characters what you want using JavaScript.

Comment: @Dog: Try `"\uD83C\uDDEF\uD83C\uDDF5"`. Flags are represented as a pair of regional indicator symbols, and it's up to the font and application to render those two separate symbols as a flag. It's a ligature.